# vim could not load library python27.dll

Tags: python

I need Windows 7 + vim + python for writing vim plugins.

```
:python print("hello")
E370: Could not load library python27.dll
E263: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python library could not be loaded.
```

Tried everything:

- reinstalled vim
- uninstalled all my 64bit python versions and installed 32bit ones
- reinstalled vim again
- restarted computer
- punched desk and keyboard
- restarted computer

Comment: For all those having the same problem: installing "cream" fixes it: http://cream.sourceforge.net  Yes - this question will probably get closed - but the fact is that there is still no solution to this anywhere on the web.

Comment: Answering your own question is good, but post it as an answer, not a comment, then accept it after two days.

Comment: compile it with python support

Comment: Hm... I am not compiling it, but rather downloading an installer.

Comment: @drozzy: there *are* installers here: https://bintray.com/veegee/generic/vim_x64. Had the same problem as you and didn't want to build Vim on my own. Simple!

Comment: Official x64 version is kept here nowadays: http://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here it goes:
For some reason installing "cream" fixes it: cream.sourceforge.net.

```
:python print("hello")
hello
```

Interestingly enough, "cream" includes a regular version of "gvim" - so I can use just that.

Answer (score 13):

**Diagnostics**

`:version` will show you if you have 32bit vim or 64bit
`python.exe` will show you if you have 32bit or 64bit python.

**Resolution**

Now it's up to you to choose either:

- 32bit vim + 32bit python *or*
- 64bit vim + 64bit python

otherwise it won't work complaining with the error you quoted.

**NB** Latest 64bit vim cannot be downloaded from the download page anymore. For some mysterious reason now there's a new special page for that:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Where_to_download_Vim

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure that you installed the same version of 32 bit python that Vim was
looking for?  I see no reason that this wouldn't have fixed your problem,
unless you somehow had a gvim exe built without python support.  Anyway, I had
precisely this problem, and the obvious thing to me was that my python dll was
x64, whilst I had 32 bit vim.  The solution for me was simply to build a 64
bit version of Vim.  I much prefer upgrading Vim to downgrading Python.  The
arguments I sent to the make file were:

```
nmake -f Make_mvc.mak GUI=yes CPU=AMD64 PYTHON=C:\Python27 DYNAMIC_PYTHON=yes PYTHON_VER=27
```

I then replaced my original 32 bit gvim.exe with the 64 bit one I just built.
Everything worked perfectly.  If you are worried about the hassle of the
build, don't be- it was very straightforward using visual studio 2010's
compilers, and running make from the appropriate visual studio command prompt
(x64 cross tools).  I can send further instructions if needed.

Comment: i was exactly in your situation. since i didn't want to recompile vim, i installed the 32bit version of python 2.7 and now gvim works like a charm!

Comment: There's a precompiled x64 version (linked from vim.org download page), installing it resolves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution that I have not seen mentioned that worked for me.

**1.** as the other answers state, make sure that the python version matches the 32/64 bit.

**2.** add `set pythondll=FULL_PATH_TO_THE_APPROPRIATE_PYTHON.DLL` to your .vimrc

for example:
`set pythondll=E:\\extern\\python27-32\\python27.dll`

**3.** reload the vimrc by either closing and restarting vim, or using `:source $MYVIMRC`

other tidbits:

- to find out where your .vimrc is `:echo $MYVIMRC`
- to easily edit your .vimrc `:e $MYVIMRC`
- to see what it is set to `:options` then `/pythondll` or `:set pythondll?`
- to test that it worked `:py import sys` followed by `:py print('Happy')`

More Info:

`:help python-dynamic`

`:help pythondll`

`:help options`

`:help source`

`:help $MYVIMRC`

edit:

Comment: On Vim 8.0 this works only without quotes (') or double quotes ("). Obviously, you path should not contain any spaces :/

Comment: good point BorisBrodski. I changed the quotes to backticks to help with any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with VIM 7.2 looking for the python25.dll This was fixed by adding the path to the python25.dll file (c:\python25\ on my system) to the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your 64-bit version of Python, at this moment, an easy to install and recent version of Vim64 for Windows can be found [here](https://bintray.com/veegee/generic/vim_x64). It even uninstalls your existing 32-bit gvim for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question: [Google drive error : python27.dll](https://superuser.com/questions/668820/google-drive-error-python27-dll)

Problem is in python27.dll dependencies. You can check this by dependencywalker utility.
Missed dll is "msvcr90.dll". It comes with "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package" and Windows 7 does not include it even with all installed updates.
You should install this package manually from:

Windows 7 x64: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336

Windows 7 32 bit: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=29

Comment: OP had already a better solution