# How do I compile gVim.exe as a 64 bit executable? (Windows 8)

Tags: windows, vim, gvim, compile, mingw

Very straight-forward question. I have downloaded mingw32 and the Vim source code and I have edited Make_mind.mak to use the correct Python version and location. I'm located in the src directory and I issue the command:

```
mingw32-make.exe -f Make_ming.mak gvim.exe
```

The compilation is successful, but when I run `:version` it says that the executable is 32 bit, and surely enough, it refuses to load my 64 bit python27.dll library.

What do I have to do to compile gvim.exe as a 64 bit executable instead?

Comment: Do you really need to build it from source?  There is a 64 bit binary at http://code.google.com/p/vim-win3264/

Comment: @heavyd: I have tried every conceivable precompiled binary in the physical universe. Trust me, none of them work 100%. Either they are 32 bit, or they are an outdated vim version, or they target the wrong Python version or none at all, or, in the **ONE** instance where I found a 64bit version of vim 7.3 compiled targeting  Python 27, I get [this fatal error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9764341/388916) every time I try using Python from gVim.

Comment: I'm assuming then that you did try that link which is gVim 7.3 with Python 2.7 support.  To compile a 64-bit executable you'll need to start with a toolset that supports 64-bit compilation: http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/

Comment: As @heavyd says, you need to install the 64 bit version of Mingw. However, if your operating system is only 32 bit it might not be that straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to compile a 64-bit version of gVim.exe using the full version of Visual Studio 2010 and the commands from [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/344100/48741):

> nmake -f Make_mvc.mak GUI=yes CPU=AMD64 PYTHON=C:\Python27 DYNAMIC_PYTHON=yes PYTHON_VER=27

It's probably possible with the [64-bit mingw toolset](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) linked by [heavyd](https://superuser.com/users/820/heavyd) too, but I couldn't find anything that worked on Windows and I wasn't about to start messing with Cygwin.

Answer (score 8):

You can check out my releases of [Vim for Windows](https://bitbucket.org/Alexander-Shukaev/vim-for-windows) to save yourself some time. It's built using [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) toolchain (don't worry, you don't need its runtime libraries for my build to work). Have support for both x86 (32-bit) and x64 (64-bit) architectures, "huge" feature set, and scripting interfaces for most popular programming languages:

- Python;
- Ruby;
- Lua;
- Perl.

Comment: Working link: https://bitbucket.org/Alexander-Shukaev/vim-for-windows

Comment: @Shrikant, fixed.