# Google drive error : python27.dll

Tags: windows-error-reporting

Evertime I open google drive I get the following error msg. 
I tried copying and pasting the dll file into system32 and sysWOW64. But the problem still persists. [image: 1]

Comment: looks like googleDrive uses pyInstaller, interestinng.

Comment: And in case anyone is wondering: Don’t even think about copying this DLL anywhere. It does not belong in the Windows folder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

May be a problem related to permissions (look for [**`System Error Codes`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Try the following.

1. Open the Windows Explorer.
2. Paste this(`%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\`) in address bar.
3. Right click on folder **`Temp`** then `Properties` - `Security` tab - `Advanced` button.
4. Click on button `Change Permissions`.
5. Remove all permissions.
6. Select the entry for your user name and click `Edit`.

   - Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent.
   - Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object.
7. Click `OK`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One fix is to set GoogleDriveSync.exe (generally located in : C:\Program Files\Google\Drive) in compatibility mode :

- Right-click on the executable -> Properties -> Compatiblity -> Run this program in compatibility mode for : Windows 7 (I assume you're running Windows 8, otherwise try setting an older OS version)

Answer (score 2):

For windows 8 system, follow the steps bellow:

1. Open the Windows Explorer.
2. Paste this(%UserProfile%\AppData\Local)
   in address bar.
3. Right click on folder Temp then Properties - Security tab - Advanced button.
4. Click in Everyone, Mark Change Permission and later click Edit
5. Mark all permissions
6. Press Ok (continue) in all windows questions.

Answer (score 1):

The option `Run as administrator` worked for me. (I'm using windows 8.1)

Comment: This worked for me. Plus, to avoid doing this every time, right click it > Properties > Compatibility > Check `Run as administrator`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, going to `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\` and deleting the `Temp` directory entirely, and then recreating it, fixed the error and allowed Google Drive to start up and sync normally.

This is a crude solution, but it worked, unlike the accepted answer, which got permission denied, even as admin. It may need to be updated for Windows 10.

Comment: Did not work ! I am running windows 10 anniversary. Only running the software as administrator works. And this is not the only application I have with issues on opening.